# Ruby syntax errors when trying to have Sass watch a directory

Tags: ruby, sass

So I'm just starting out with Sass, so far I've updated my Ruby installation, installed Sass and created two practice directories and one .scss file. But when I get to the step where I tell sass to watch both my scss and css directories, I get this large dump of errors in my command prompt:

```
C:\sasstest>sass --watch scss:css
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2054:
 warning: else without rescue is useless
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2060:
 warning: else without rescue is useless
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2099:
 warning: else without rescue is useless
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `re
quire': C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.
rb:2050: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if (SyntaxError)
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2054:
 syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2060:
 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2095:
 syntax error, unexpected modifier_if
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2099:
 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2885:
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:34
:in `<module:Script>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:8:
in `<module:Sass>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:3:
in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:47
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass.rb:99:in `<t
op (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/bin/sass:6:in `<top (
required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/bin/sass:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby21/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'

C:\sasstest>
```

I should note that even watching the two files directly gets me the same result. Any advice?

My current version of Ruby btw is: 2.6.12

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have ruby **2.6.12** since the latest release is **2.4.2** ([ruby releases](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/)). To get the ruby version run

```
ruby -version
```

in terminal. Most likely you'd have **2.1.0**.

**2.6.12** is the  version of RubyGems - to check it run

```
gem --version
```

The problem you have looks like incompatibility of versions of saas and ruby - saas 3.5.1 is not compatible with ruby versions below **2.1.3** according to this [issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10279). So you need to update the ruby version.